# Windows blue screen restart loop

Tags: windows-10, troubleshooting

Hi I am stucked at the blue screen restart loop. I just installed the new version of Windows 10 and then I removed some programms I manually installed earlier. I have to mention that sometimes when playing a game the driver just lost his actuality and I had to actualize it again. 
I tried entering in safe mode but that diednt work either. Them I downgraded from the boot menu back to my earlier version and have still the same problem but no I cant access the boot menu because of the windows defender offline.

So I loaded UEFI defaults in Bios and still no change. Even with the recovery disc i had no chance. There are only three documents i want to rescue the rest ist saved in clouds. So is there a possibility to start this damn windows pc? Can I install ubuntu on it and access the documents? I appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the error code reported by the blue screen?

Comment: Inaccasible boot device

Comment: I would try running a hard drive tester. There are a few out there that exist. Sounds like either a bad drive or controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just rebooted from usb and didnt install directly but first went to repair options so I could update the drivers. But instead of searching the drivers in the folder system I searched my needed files and copied them to another usb stick. Partition wasnt able I tried this first... so I formated the disc and installed windows from scratch. Now I just have to install everythink from the beginning but thats cool to me.

Answer (score 0):

The blue screen comes under two cases, either in hardware change or not supported.

Remove the power supply, keep pressed power button for 30-40 sec. And reinstall again. It may work

Comment: Do you mean remove the power cord, or do you really mean for them to remove the entire power supply?

Comment: Also, BSODs are not limited to those two cases.